# Error "document is not defined" when executing electron

Tags: javascript, d3.js, electron

I would like to create an app by using Electron with a tiny html and js scripts and d3.js library.

package.json

```
{
  "name": "Test_Report9",
"version": "1.0.0",
"main": "report9.js",
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "ISC",
"description": "",
"jsdom": "9.12.0"
}
```

JavaScript(report9.js)

```
const d3 = require('d3');
svg = d3.select("div").append("svg")
    .attr("id", "chart")
    .attr("width", WIDTH)
    .attr("height", HEIGHT);
```

With them, when executing the electron ($ electron path), an error message "document is not defined" is displayed.

```
App threw an error during load
ReferenceError: document is not defined
    at Object.select (/Users/hnishim/node_modules/d3-selection/build/d3-selection.js:925:25)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/hnishim/Documents/MOLCURE/Electron/Test_Report9_3/src/report9.js:11:10)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/hnishim/Documents/MOLCURE/Electron/Test_Report9_3/src/report9.js:426:3)
    at Module._compile (module.js:571:32)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:580:10)
    at Module.load (module.js:488:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (module.js:447:12)
    at Function.Module._load (module.js:439:3)
    at loadApplicationPackage (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/default_app.asar/main.js:283:12)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/electron/dist/Electron.app/Contents/Resources/default_app.asar/main.js:325:5)
```

Does anyone know the reason and how to solve it?

Comment: The file that you specify for the `main` property in the package.json is the file that starts the main process. You need to open a window and run d3 in the renderer process. Take a look at the [docs](https://electron.atom.io/docs/tutorial/quick-start/).

Comment: Thanks!  This issue is solved based on Peter's comment.
What I did is;
 - create another js file (main.js) which is the one exactly same as the example Peter's link shows.
 - change the parameter for "main" to "main.js" to use the main.js I just created